# Rearrangements and absolute convergence

Tags: real-analysis

[It is a theorem that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Rearrangements_and_unconditional_convergence)

If $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N}a_n$ converges absolutely then any rearrangement also converges and to the same limit.

Does the converse hold? That's if any rearrangment of $\sum_n a_n$ converges then $\sum_n a_n$ converges absolutely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If $\displaystyle \sum_n a_n$ converges conditionally, you can rearrange it so that it diverges.  Infinitely many of the $a_n$'s are positive and infinitely many are negative. Both series $$ \sum_{a_n \ge 0} a_n \quad \text{and} \sum_{a_n \le 0} a_n$$ must be divergent if the full series converges conditionally. To construct a divergent rearrangement, you add up positive terms until the sum exceeds $1$, then add a negative term. Next add positive terms until the sum exceeds $2$, then add a negative term. Then add positive terms until the sum exceeds $3$, and so on.

This can be modified to make the rearrangement converge to any specified real number.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate why the statement "If $\sum a_n$ converges conditionally you can rearrange it so that it diverges" implies that "If every rearrangement converges then $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely"?

Comment: If a series is known to converge, the contrapositive of "if every rearrangement converges then the series converges absolutely" is "if the series converges conditionally then there exists a divergent rearrangement"

Comment: @blue: look up the [Riemann Rearrangement Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) and [Contraposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).